# ¿Cómo obtener el formato de una imagen enviada por un usuario con discord js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, discord.js

Estoy tratando de obtener la imagen enviada por un usuario en un canal de discord de tal manera que pueda enviarla en un embed después no me es posible obtenerla por msg.content, he intentado de varias forma pero no he podido hacerlo.

Gracias de antemano.

```
 if (msg.content.startsWith(`${prefi}tw`)) { // the command for te announcement
    const embed = new RichEmbed()
    .setColor("#3ded97") //message line color "Green"
    .setImage(msg.content()) //Image from the message 
    .setFooter(`God • ${dia.toLocaleDateString()}`); //The base from the text with date and the sender
msg.delete(); //Delete the message from the user 
msg.channel.send(embed);
}
```

Comment: Faltan detalles en tu pregunta. ¿Qué versión de DiscordJS? ¿Tienes algún error? ¿Cuál? ¿Has leido la documentación de tu versión de DiscordJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para empezar, [`message.content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content) es una **propiedad** (No un método) que devuelve el texto (Contenido) del mensaje como una [**String**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String)

Si quieres mostrar un archivo adjunto del mensaje en la imagen del embed, para a los archivos adjuntos del mensaje puedes usar [`message.attachments`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v11/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments), esto devuelve una [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection), para acceder al primer archivo adjunto del mensaje usa [`message.attachments.first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection?scrollTo=first)

*Ten en cuenta que el archivo el primer adjunto no tiene que ser necesariamente una imagen, [por lo que te conviene hacer algo en caso de que este no sea una imagen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473185/regex-javascript-image-file-extension)*